# Angular pass parameters from html to component using ngx-smart-modal

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters

I am using ngx-smart-modal in my project to pass value from html to component when is open . According to official doc of [ngx-smart-modal](https://maximelafarie.com/ngx-smart-modal/#/events) l can handle events directly from the view . but l have undefined parameters .

HTML :

```
 <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of storeData">                         <!--  pass from here -->
 <div class="card-body text-right"(click)="ngxSmartModalService.getModal('addjob').open(item)">
  <a> 
 {{item?.title?.catname}}
 </a>
  </div>
 </div>

<!--  modal view -->
  <ngx-smart-modal #addjob identifier="addjob">
   <h1>hello</h1>
 </ngx-smart-modal>
```

Ts

```
  constructor(public ngxSmartModalService: NgxSmartModalService) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.ngxSmartModalService.getModal('addjob').onOpen.subscribe((modal) => {
        console.log('opened!', modal.getData());
      });
    }
```

output console : `undefined` any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my own solution .

TS :

```
  openaddjob(a){
    this.ngxSmartModalService.create('addjob', 'content').open();
    this.ngxSmartModalService.setModalData(a, 'addjob');

    console.log(a)
  }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of storeData">
 <div class="card-body text-right"(click)="openModal(item)">
  <a> 
 {{item?.title?.catname}}
 </a>
  </div>
 </div>

<!--  modal view -->
  <ngx-smart-modal #addjob identifier="addjob">
   <div *ngIf="addjob.hasData()">
    <pre>{{ addjob.getData() | json }}</pre>
  </div>
    <!-- output
    {
        "$key": "12122211",
        "title": {
          "catname": "Food"
        }
      } -->
 </ngx-smart-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to open the modal programmatically just **set data forcefully before opening modal.**

```
this.ngxSmartModalService.setModalData({val: 1}, 'yourModalIdenitifier', true);
this.ngxSmartModalService.open("yourModalIdenitifier");
```

On another component (where you have a modal)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.ngxSmartModalService.getModal('yourModalIdenitifier').onOpen.subscribe((modal) => {
  console.log('opened!', modal.getData()); // will print opened! {val: 1}
}); 
}
```

Happy Coding!!